# React Native NavigatorIOS error: Element type is invalid expected a string or a class/function

Tags: react-native

> Element type is invalid: expected a string(for built-in components) or
>   a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. check
>   the render method of 'NavigatorIOS'.

Here is my code

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 */
'use strict';

import React, {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  NavigatorIOS,
  View,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';

var Dashboard = require('./App/Views/Dashboard/index.ios.js');

class HackerNews extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (

            <NavigatorIOS style={styles.container}
                tintColor='#FF6600'
                initialRoute={{
                    title: 'Hacker News',
                    Component: Dashboard,
                }}/>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#F6F6FF',
  },

});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('HackerNews', () => HackerNews);
```

Dashboard code:

```
'use strict';

import React, {
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    TouchableHighlight,
} from 'react-native';

//var api = require("../../Network/api.js");
//var Post = require("../Post/index.ios.js");

export default class Dashboard extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            topStoryIDs: null,
            lastIndex: 0
        };
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <Text>Dashboard Testing</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Updates:

figured it out. component should be lowercase.

Comment: Did you forget to import `Dashboard` class before `HackerNews`' class definition , may be?

Answer (score 2):

*Already @qinking126 able to solve this problem and he commented his answer.*

***I am just highlighting his Answer Here.***

```
<NavigatorIOS style={styles.container}
            tintColor='#FF6600'
            initialRoute={{
                title: 'Hacker News',
                Component: Dashboard,
            }}/>
```

*Here* ***Component*** *should be in lowercase*

*Like this:-* ***component: Dashboard,***

***Thanks to qinking126***

Comment: This should be either a comment on that other answer, or submitted as a suggested edit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the Dashboard class in the HackerNews component.

Comment: did you check if the import returns something else than undefined?

Comment: never mind. i figured it out. component should be lowercase.